# Nginx static files 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to configure nginx to serve static files from a directory. And getting 403 Forbidden when trying to access the path /static/

Here is parts from my config:

```
user root;
<...>
http {
    <...>
    server {
        <...>
        location /static/
        {
            alias /home/my_user/static/;
            autoindex on;
        }
        <...>
    }
}
```

I also have permissions 777 recursive for `/home/my_user/static/` and yes i have index.html inside the directory. And still getting the error. Why?

os: Centos 7

Comment: What's in `error.log`?

Comment: nothing special. `2018/10/12 14:39:17 [error] 23590#0: *1 open() "/home/my_user/static/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: <my_ip>, server: _, request: "GET /static/index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "<my_host>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling flag

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content true
```

Solves the problem.

Thx to https://serverfault.com/questions/899187/nginx-static-file-configuration-for-cenotos-7-minimal-installation